# how to save toggle button prefrence in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vuejs3

i have a togle button which uses useTimeoutPoll plugin to fetch some data in 10 seconds intervals, i want to save the state of this togle button to local storage but i cant figure out how to do it, please if anyone can help. this is the code below

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  await data.loadUpdate(id)
}
const { isActive, pause, resume } = useTimeoutPoll(fetchData, 10000)

const toggleUpdate = computed(() => {
  if (isActive) {
    return resume
  } else return pause
})
```

and i use the togle like this

```
    <Toggle
      v-model="isActive"
      @click="toggleUpdate"
    >
      <span>
        update
      </span>
    </Toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. localStorage save item
   `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`
2. localStorage take item
   `localStorage.getItem(key)`
3. localStorage remove item
   `localStorage.removeItem(key)`

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
const toggleUpdate = computed(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('isActive', isActive)
  if (isActive) {
    return resume
  } else return pause
})
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: i tried this before but it will only save the false value. Thanks anyway. i got it to work

Comment: Plz try again `localStorage.setItem('isActive', isActive)`